# Terraform - Google cloud - create multiple service accounts with multiple roles

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'd like to grant multiple Bigquery user roles to multiple service accounts.
With `for_each` in Terraform, I can only use 1 variable. How can I use 2 `for_each` in one resource. Below is the code I tried:

`main.tf` has below:

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "bq_access" {
  for_each = toset(var.bigquery_user_role_list)
  project = var.project
  role = [ for role in var.bq_roles : "${role}" ]
  member  = each.value
}
```

`variables.tf` has below:

```
variable "bigquery_user_role_list" {}

  variable "bq_roles" {
    type = set(string)
    default = ["roles/bigquery.viewer",
               "roles/bigquery.reader"
    ]
  }
```

Error:

> role = [ for role in var.bq_roles : "${role}" ]

> var.bq_roles is set of string with 2 elements
>
> Inappropriate value for attribute "role": string required.

Comment: You can nest the for loop